# how can I solve this error in ionic `You must specify a "protocol" for the proxy type`

Tags: ionic-framework

I ran `ionic` start series `sidetabs` in my `Windows` and got this error

[image]

```
TypeError: You must specify a "protocol" for the proxy type (http, https, socks, socks4, socks4a, socks5, socks5h, pac+data, pac+file, pac+ftp, pac+http, pac+https)
    at new ProxyAgent (C:\Users\sato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-proxy\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:97:11)
    at ProxyAgent (C:\Users\sato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-proxy\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:81:45)
    at Request.proxy (C:\Users\sato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-proxy\node_modules\superagent-proxy\index.js:71:15)
    at C:\Users\sato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\http.js:31:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\sato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:102:62)
    at <anonymous>
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, enter the `SET` command without quotes. The plugin cannot identify the protocol from the url if the text contains quotes. Might get fixed in future. As of now, this worked for me,

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.company.com:port-number
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.company.com:port-number
set IONIC_HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.company.com:port-number
set PROXY=http
```

This applies if your proxy is an HTTP proxy. If you have a SOCK proxy, you need to edit accordingly changing the url and `proxy=sock`

Comment: Try "set proxy=http"

Comment: This worked for me as is (my machine runs on windows 10). Thank you!

Comment: Am getting the same issue, is this setup is rite? set HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8100
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:8100
set IONIC_HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8100
set PROXY=http

Answer (score 0):

my problem was solved with the command **npm config unset -g proxy**